# Why can't gcc and msvc compiled C object files linked together?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, abi

As far as I know, **C(not C++)** has a stable ABI on each OS, and mainstream compilers often stand with that. Many languages may link with code written in C, and e.g. [SystemV AMD64](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf) documents at page 10 that :

> No attempt has been made to specify an ABI for languages other than C. However, it is assumed that many programming languages will wish to link with code
> written in C, so that the ABI specifications documented here apply there too.

So I tried to link C code compiled by msvc and by gcc in Windows:

```c
// msvcF.c, compiled by msvc.
#include "msvcF.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
    printf("compiled version from msvc!\n");
    return;
}
```

```c
// msvcF.h
void test();
```

```c
// gccF.c, compiled by gcc.
#include "msvcF.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello from gcc compiled code!\n");
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

And the command is as below:

```bash
cl /c msvcF.c # This is in VS2019 x86-64 env, msvc 19.29.
gcc -c gccF.c # gcc 8.1.0
```

When I tried to link `gccF.o` and `msvcF.obj`, if using gcc's linker as :

```bash
gcc -O gccF.o msvcF.obj
```

It prompts: `Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file`. And when I tried to use msvc's linker as :

```bash
link gccF.o msvcF.obj # This is in VS2019 x86-64 env, msvc 19.29.
```

It prompts: `gccF.o: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol '__main' referenced in function 'main'`.

I also tried to add `-mabi=ms` in the gcc command, but it doesn't work.

So I'm quite confused; does it mean C ABI is not regulated or determined by the OS or mainstream compilers don't try to obey that? I mean C++ ABI is determined by both the compiler and OS, so if C is also so, what's the point of saying the latter is compitable?

Comment: the object file format has nothing to do with the ABI

Comment: Object file is the state before linking. The ABI applies in the next step, when the code is linked and becomes machine code. In general, C programmers need not worry their pretty heads about ABI except when it comes to stating the calling convention explicitly - for example stdcall vs cdecl.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry for my questions, but now I'm totally messed up. I've read [N4028](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4028.pdf) by Herb Sutter saying that ABI is to let code be able to somehow link together.

Comment: Well sure, two separate linkers meeting the same ABI must generate the same code, when it comes to things like calling convention. But that isn't related to object files.

Comment: @Lundin So you mean that OS ABI doesn't guarantee compilers to generate inter-linkable object files, but to guarantee if they are inter-linkable, the machine code can run on the OS? But then what's the merit of C ABI over C++ ABI considering both of them have to use inter-linkable object files?

Comment: Isn't the problem here simply the fact that the linker cannot link two object files from two very different compilers (MS compiler and gcc)?

Comment: ABI is mainly related to a specific compiler and ultimately the CPU. x86 PC being a special snowflake since it historically had many different kinds of calling conventions, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions. There's nothing called "C ABI" or "C++ ABI"... if object files from C can be linked by your C++ linker it very likely is because they are part of the same compiler tool chain.

Comment: @Lundin I'd like to extend my gratitude for your patience to answer my stupid questions. So what does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490134/15582103) mean by saying "interoperable" in "Most C compilers on Windows use this as their default calling convention, and thus are interoperable" and so-called C/C++ ABI?

Comment: @o_oTurtle In the x86 Windows would, the stdcall and cdecl calling conventions are the common ones. That answer just says that a C or C++ compiler using cdecl might have compatibility problems calling the Windows API. This would be because most the Windows API is pre-linked in the form of Dynamic Load Libraries (DLL) and in the stdcall format. So whenever importing a DLL or creating one, you'll have to be careful about specifying the correct calling convention - most of the time stdcall. But this also means that you can call DLLs created in wildly different languages.

Comment: Though when you type `#include <windows.h>` this is already handled for you by the compiler. So in the Windows world, pretty much the only time you have to actually worry about calling convention is when creating/importing custom DLLs.